# Same command sequence produces different results in command-line and script

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, zsh, macos

I'm writing a utility script to help me delete Git branches in zsh. Currently, it looks like this:

```bsh
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/ |
    while read -r line; do
        printf "remove %s? (y/n)" $line;
        read ans </dev/tty;
        case "$ans" in 
            y|Y) echo "$line";;
        esac;
    done
```

This works and prints the branches one by one as I respond to the input prompt.
[image]

However, when I run this same command sequence directly from the command line and not as a script, the first branch is skipped.

`git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/ | while read -r line; do printf "remove %s? (y/n)" $line; read ans </dev/tty; case "$ans" in y|Y) echo "$line";; esac; done`

[image]

Any idea why this difference in behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: You question says *" in zsh"* - but you appear to be running the script with `sh`

Comment: Research: (1) It's true your first try uses `sh`, not `zsh`. I believe your second try ("directly from the command line") is in `zsh`. (2) I think `zsh` runs the last element of a pipeline in the main shell; the `read -r </dev/tty` is a builtin of your interactive `zsh`. (3) Presumably there is some bug(?), race condition(?) or something that causes the shell perform `read` when it's not yet in the foreground process group. My hypothesis is it gets SIGTTIN and one (may be more) early `read` fails. I may be wrong, running the last element of the pipeline in a subshell seems to help though. Or…

Comment: (cont'd) … or adding a "useless" `| cat`, so the `cat` is last in the pipe.

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry for the confusion. Indeed, when I run `sh -c 'git for-each-ref...'` in the CLI, it works. Are you aware of a way I can save that as an alias?

Comment: @OmarSharaki If you have the script available, just put it in your `PATH` and you're good. (Wieth `#/bin/sh` shebang)

Answer (score 0):

In  `zsh`, like in `ksh`, the last component of a pipeline runs in the current shell, not in a subshell.

When you run a job in foreground in an interactive shell instance, the shell creates a new process group and makes that process group the foreground process group of the terminal. Then all processes that it spawns in the job it puts in that process group.

However, in a:

```
cmd | { some-builtin; some-builtin; }
```

It's the main shell process that runs `some-builtin`. And that process is already a process group leader, so cannot be put in the foreground process group. That means it remains in background for as long as the process running `cmd` has not exited.

A process that is not in the foreground process group cannot read from its controlling terminal. If it does so, it's suspended with a `SIGTTIN` signal, and if it ignores those signals (like the main process of an interactive shell does), the `read()` system call fails with a EIO error.

The only reason you don't see the same in ksh93 is that its `read` builtin does a `select()`/`poll()` before reading, so you would only get a EIO if typing something before `git` returns.

In `zsh`, there are even more severe problems in that for instance in:

```
cmd1 | { cmd2; cmd3; }
```

`cmd1` and `cmd2` will be put in the same process group and in foreground, but upon running `cmd3`, zsh makes itself back the foreground process group resulting in both `cmd1` and `cmd3` being in background:

```
~$ (sleep 1; cat) | { ps -opid,pgid,tpgid,stat,args; ps -opid,pgid,tpgid,stat,args; sleep 2; echo done; }
    PID    PGID   TPGID STAT COMMAND
 571038  571038  653553 Ss   zsh
 653553  653553  653553 S+   zsh
 653554  653553  653553 S+   sleep 1
 653555  653553  653553 R+   ps -opid,pgid,tpgid,stat,args
    PID    PGID   TPGID STAT COMMAND
 571038  571038  571038 Ss+  zsh
 653553  653553  571038 S    zsh
 653554  653553  571038 S    sleep 1
 653556  653553  571038 R    ps -opid,pgid,tpgid,stat,args
zsh: suspended (tty input)  sleep 2
$ ps -opid,pgid,tpgid,stat,args
    PID    PGID   TPGID STAT COMMAND
 571038  571038  654415 Ss   zsh
 653553  653553  654415 T    cat
 653557  653553  654415 T    sleep 2
 653558  653558  654415 T    zsh
 654415  654415  654415 R+   ps -opid,pgid,tpgid,stat,args
```

(the `+` means in foreground, TPGID is the foreground process group)

Here, you can work around the problems by running either the whole pipe line, or the rightmost element in a subshell:

```
(git | while ...; done)
```

Or:

```
git | (while ...; done)
```

This kind of problem doesn't happen in scripts as the shell does not do job control when not interactive. All the processes in the script are run in the same process group which will be either in foreground or background (assuming it's run in a terminal) depending on how it was invoked by the shell that started it.